# NoMethodError (undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007fe5554268b8>): app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am new to rails. Everything is working fine locally but after deploying on heroku its giving me the above error.

Here is the posts_controllers action:

```
 def new
   @post = current_user.posts.build
 end
```

and here is the schema.rb file content:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160516214156) do

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name:    "index_comments_on_post_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
 end

 add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique:   true
 add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Can you show us error, which you are facing

Comment: I just solved the problem :)

Comment: @Umerror In case, you yourself solved the problem, please post the answer to your question, and accept it so that other can benefit from it. After all, that's what the purpose of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure, I just reset my database on heroku by running
 heroku run rake db:reset  and after that I migrated again by running heroku run rake db:migrate.

Comment: As @ArslanAli said, put the solution as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
To solve the problem, I specified `:foreign_key` of has_many relation.

My case:

`class Assay::Attempt::Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assay_attempt, class_name: 'Assay::Attempt'
end`

`class Assay::Attempt < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, foreign_key: :assay_attempt_id # there wasn't foreign_key option
end`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as well on Rails 4.2.0, in my case everything seemed to be ok, since I had the foreign_key specified, what fixed the issue was when the foreign_key and foreign_type were specified as a string, not as a symbol:

```
has_many :answers, foreign_key: :assay_attempt_id  #this was not working
has_many :answers, foreign_key: 'assay_attempt_id' #this was ok
```